# Correct gradle directory in adndroid studio (for windows)

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Which is the correct directory to unzip my gradle 6.3 to cause it to unzip into my sdk (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\gradle-6.3) ?
I am having trouble running the studio both offline and online.
I have downloaded the necessary offline component/plugings.

Comment: Which directories have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is not a part of Android SDK, so you should not place it in android sdk folder. There is a good installation instruction  on [official site](https://gradle.org/install/)